# WAR extension strategy in Wildfly

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, war, wildfly

In a WildFly-project, I have a big WAR-File (about 100 MB) which contains the whole application in JAR-Files (EJBs, GUI, Web Services etc)

In this WAR, there are some Functions which implement a custom `Function` interface (there are also other classes like `AbstractFunction` and so on). Now I would like to extend the application with user-provided functions (they should be on the class path which can then be accessed by the application.

The problem is that I can't deploy the functions before the main WAR because `Function`, `AbstractFunction` etc. are the the WAR which is not yet deployed.

Adding a WildFly module with the functions fails for the same reason.

One possibility would be to restructure the WAR file so that `Function`, `AbstractionFunction` are in an own jar which is deployed separately. Unfortunately, this would be a major refactoring which is not possible at the time being.

So is the only (simple) possibility to put the user-defined functions in a JAR into the WAR-file?

Comment: With your problems at the time being, why not redeploy the `Function` with every deployment and use independent class loaders (probably the default) for every Wildfly module?

Comment: Do you mean putting `Function` into the JAR of the user-defined module? If so , the problem is that it is unfortunately on one or a few classes, but many since there is no modularization in this WAR

Answer (score 1):

You can deploy user code as independent jar/war with EJB. EJB implements `Function`. Main module can lookup and find them through JNDI. Also you have to make common classes like `Function` and DTO available for user modules and for main war. The simplest way is share classes from main war. You can add META-INF/jboss-deployment-structure.xml to client modules:

```
<jboss-deployment-structure xmlns="urn:jboss:deployment-structure:1.2">
<deployment>
    <dependencies>
        <module name="deployment.main.war"/>
    </dependencies>
  </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

PS

I have similar project with structure:

- core.war contains Plugin interface
- set of plugin*.jar (dependent from core.war)

In my core.war I have code like:

```
 Plugin srv = (Plugin) new InitialContext().lookup(jndi);
```

And my plugin looks like:

```
 @Stateless
 public class UserPlugin implements Plugin
```

JNDI looks like `java:global/user-plugin/UserPlugin`

Comment: Yes, but the problem in my specific case is that it would be way too much work to seperate these classes and create the main.war, since the code base is not modularized. So far, my only idea is to put everyhing in the WAR file anyway. Or are there any hacks possible?

Comment: May be I don't catch you, but you already have big war (I called it main.war). You don't need change it. But new user defined implementations of `Function` can be placed into new small jar's. These jar's will have access to all classes from big war (see jboss-deployment-structure.xml).

Comment: The problem is that it is some kind of circular dependency. main.war should be extended by user-defined functions but these functions should also be available in the classpath of main.war

Comment: As I say main war should use JNDI lookup for client implementation of `Function` interface. It means that EJB breaks dependency loop. Main war depends only from `Function` interface.

Comment: Well I tried to include main.war in the plugin.jar but when including main.war as a dependency it seems that the EJBs of main.war are loaded again, because they are now in the classpath of plugin.jar^. Did you have any similar problems?

Comment: What means include? I only add depedency in META-INF/jboss-deployment-structure.xml. If you use maven you should use scope provided in jar pom.xml for main artifact.

Comment: When in include my main.war file in the jar, does this not bean, the content of the war file becomes part of the class path of  jar? and wildfly scans the jar for EJBs etc.